Cannot make Remix working with @module-federation/vite
I am trying to create a Proof of Concept of a federated app, that is a microfrontend based app, where:

the host is a Remix app, which federation is configured using @module-federation/vite
the remote is the mfe to be consumed that I generate with just Vite and @module-federation/vite module.

The core idea is to have a Remix app that loads a mfe when navigating to a particular route, in my test it is /mfe.
While on the mfe side everything is working fine and I can create the mfe file correctly, I cannot make the host Remix app build when I add the federation plugin to its vite.config.ts.
Here is the error, please note that I want to keep ssr: true in host app (which is Remix default value):
vite v5.4.10 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 0 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 12ms
[add-entry] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\DEV\poc_remix\virtual:remix\server-build'
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:441:20)
    at Object.buildStart (C:\DEV\poc_remix\node_modules\@module-federation\vite\lib\index.cjs:109:41)
    at file:///C:/DEV/poc_remix/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20789:40  
    at async Promise.all (index 8)
    at async PluginDriver.hookParallel (file:///C:/DEV/poc_remix/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20717:9)
    at async file:///C:/DEV/poc_remix/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21664:13
    at async catchUnfinishedHookActions (file:///C:/DEV/poc_remix/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21135:16)
    at async rollupInternal (file:///C:/DEV/poc_remix/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21661:5)
    at async Module.build (file:///C:/DEV/poc_remix/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:65443:14)
    at async viteBuild (C:\DEV\poc_remix\node_modules\@remix-run\dev\dist\vite\build.js:212:5) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'PLUGIN_ERROR',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\DEV\\poc_remix\\virtual:remix\\server-build',
  pluginCode: 'ENOENT',
  plugin: 'add-entry',
  hook: 'buildStart'
}

Inspired by official module federation examples, here are my configuration files.
The host vite.config.ts config file:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    federation({
      name: "remix_host",
      remotes: {
        mfe: {
          type: "module",
          name: "mfe",
          entry: "http://localhost:3000/mfe.js",
        },
      },
      exposes: {},
      filename: "mfe.js",
      shared: {
        react: { singleton: true },
      },
    }),
    remix({
      future: {
        v3_fetcherPersist: true,
        v3_relativeSplatPath: true,
        v3_throwAbortReason: true,
        v3_singleFetch: true,
        v3_lazyRouteDiscovery: true,
      },
      routes: (defineRoutes) =>
        defineRoutes((route) => {
          route("/", "routes/home.tsx", { index: true });
          route("/mfe", "routes/test-mfe.tsx");
        }),
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
  build: {
    target: "chrome89",
  },
});

The remote mfe vite.config.ts config file:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    federation({
      name: "mfe",
      filename: "mfe.js",
      exposes: {
        "./mfeButton": "./src/mfeButton",
      },
      remotes: {},
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
        },
      },
    }),
    react(),
  ],
  build: {
    target: "chrome89",
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
});

The host app package.json deps sections:
"dependencies": {
    "@module-federation/vite": "^1.1.5",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.13.1",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.13.1",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.13.1",
    "isbot": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.13.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^5.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
  },

The remote mfe package.json deps section:
"dependencies": {
    "@module-federation/vite": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.10"
  }

Here is the test-mfe.tsx:
/* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
import { lazy } from "react";

const RemoteMfeButton = lazy(
  async () =>
    // @ts-expect-error loading remote
    await import("mfe/mfeButton")
);

export default function TestMFE() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>I AM A MFE</p>
      <RemoteMfeButton />
    </>
  );
}

In the host vite.config.ts file I tried:

drop all Remix future flag
add/remove entryGlobalName: 'remote' and shareScope: 'default' in federation configuration
add/remove manifest: true to federation configuration
reordering plugin list within the config

But error did not change. If I remove federation config, then Remix app builds normally.
My questions are:

Is there any Remix limitation to work with @module-federation/vite that I am not aware of?
Perhaps the limitation is on @module-federation/vite side, and not in Remix?
The error happens on the server-build so perhaps I should find a way of isolating federation build step only for the client side build? If so, any idea on how to do that?

I see these possible workarounds, but I would like to avoid them:

having Remix loading an external module built in plain Vite, so that I can leverage @module-federation/vite without mixing it up with Remix. Such module will be the host and will actually just bridge the remote mfe loading
manage the mfe loading directly, basically writing a very custom module federation plugin for host. Something that I would like to avoid.

